# CommandButton in jsf

Tags: jsf, primefaces

In my code the CommandButton action does not work when I put it in the second or third  PanelGroup. It only works when I put in the first PanelGroup.  My code is shown below.  What may be the problem?

```
<ui:define name="pageLocations">
    <h:panelGroup layout="block" id="pageLocations">
        <c:if test="#{param.typeTab == null &amp;&amp; param.relationTab == null &amp;&amp; param.propertyTab == null}">
            <ui:param name="defaultHeaderTitle" value="Properties"/>
            <!--<h:outputText value="Properties" />--> 
        </c:if>
        <p class="breadcrumb">Admin <ezcomp:out value="raquo" /> 
            Fields <ezcomp:out value="raquo" /> 
            <strong>
                #{param.pageHeaderTitle}#{defaultHeaderTitle} 
            </strong>
        </p>
    </h:panelGroup>
</ui:define>
<!--<ui:define></ui:define>-->
<ui:define name="pageHeaderTitle">
    <h:outputText value="#{param.pageHeaderTitle}#{defaultHeaderTitle}" id="soso" /> 
</ui:define>

<ui:define name="sidemenu">
    <ui:param name="fieldsPage" value="active"/>
</ui:define>

<ui:define name="admin-content">
    <h:form prependId="false">
        <h:panelGroup layout="block" class="well well-small" id="mainPanel">
            <h:panelGroup layout="block" class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span1"><ezcomp:out value="nbsp"/></div>
                <div class="span4">
                    <ul class="nav nav-pills" style="margin-top:4px;margin-bottom:0">
                        <c:if test="#{param.typeTab == null &amp;&amp; param.relationTab == null &amp;&amp; param.propertyTab == null }">
                            <ui:param name="default" value="active"/>
                            <ui:param name="defaultHeaderTitle" value="Properties"/>
                        </c:if>
                        <li class="#{param.propertyTab} #{default}">
                            <p:commandLink  value="Properties" immediate="true" update="mainPanel,fields,:soso,:pageLocations" >
                                <f:param name="propertyTab" value="active"/>
                                <f:param name="pageHeaderTitle" value="Properties"/> 
                            </p:commandLink>
                        </li>
                        <li class="#{param.typeTab}">
                            <p:commandLink  value="Types" immediate="true" async="true" update="mainPanel,fields,:soso,:pageLocations" >
                                <f:param name="typeTab" value="active"/>
                                <f:param name="pageHeaderTitle" value="Types"/>
                            </p:commandLink>
                        </li>
                        <li class="#{param.relationTab}">
                            <p:commandLink value="Fields Relations" immediate="true" update="mainPanel,fields,:soso,:pageLocations">
                                <f:param name="relationTab" value="active"/>
                                <f:param name="pageHeaderTitle" value="Fields Relations"/>
                            </p:commandLink>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

            </h:panelGroup>
        </h:panelGroup>
        <h:panelGrid id="fields" width="100%">

            <h:panelGroup layout="block" rendered="#{param.propertyTab == 'active' || default == 'active' }">
                <ui:include src="property/properties.xhtml"></ui:include>
            </h:panelGroup>
            <h:panelGroup layout="block" rendered="#{param.typeTab == 'active'}">
                <ui:include src="type/types.xhtml"></ui:include>
            </h:panelGroup>
            <h:panelGroup layout="block" rendered="#{param.relationTab == 'active'}">
                <ui:include src="fields-relations.xhtml"></ui:include>
                <h:commandButton value="Create" actionListener="#{fieldsRelationsController.createRelations()}"  >
                    <f:ajax listener="#{fieldsRelationsController.createRelations()}"/>
                </h:commandButton>

            </h:panelGroup>

        </h:panelGrid>

    </h:form>
</ui:define>
```

Comment: why there are 2 listener calls  <h:commandButton value="Create" actionListener="#{fieldsRelationsController.createRelations()}"  >
                    <f:ajax listener="#{fieldsRelationsController.createRelations()}"/>
                </h:commandButton>
Did you get any parser error ? since you are using () in action call.

Comment: @Stivel: the double listener call is strange, but the EL syntax is perfectly valid since Java EE 6 / EL 2.2 (already out since 2009, keep yourself up to date).

Comment: but not problem in listener it work when i put the commandButton in the first <h:panelGroup>

Comment: thanks a lot Stivel and BalusC for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because those panel groups are conditionally rendered based on a request parameter which is not present anymore in the subsequent POST request initiated by the command button.

When JSF processes the POST request, the `rendered` condition is also re-evaluated. Due to lack of the request parameter, it evaluates `false`, so the command button component won't be processed, so the associated action won't be invoked.

To fix this, you need to pass the request parameter responsible for calculating the result of the `rendered` attribute in a `<f:param>` of the command button.

```
<h:commandButton value="Create" action="#{fieldsRelationsController.createRelations}">
    <f:ajax />
    <f:param name="relationTab" value="active"/>
</h:commandButton>
```

*(note that I've replaced the `actionListener` by `action` and removed the double `f:ajax listener` as well, I don't know what you were thinking, but I'll assume it to be a leftover of unthoughtful shoots in the dark)*

#### See also:

- [commandButton/commandLink/ajax action/listener method not invoked or input value not updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/hcommandlink-hcommandbutton-is-not-being-invoked/2120183#2120183) - point 5.